# sed command - Naming captured group

Tags: regex, sed, substitution, regex-group

Back references (e.g. "\3") are not very practical when you are writing a substitution command using *sed* with many captured groups (e.g. to convert an access log line to another format).

Beside, if you add another capture group at the beginning, you have to update the substitution pattern too, i.e. adding +1 to all back references.

So, is there a way to name captured group in *sed* command instead of using back-references?

Comment: there is no such feature in sed, maybe you can use perl instead ?

Comment: How would you assign the names to the groups?

Comment: Consider sharing your sed script, sample input/output. This will help SO reader provide you with answers

Answer (score 0):

`sed` does not support named backreferences.

Perl supports them, and you may specify any amount of named capturing groups with the same name in the pattern:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<i>b)ash|(?<i>sl)ash|(?<i>m)ash/$+{i}ong/g' <<< "bash slash mash"
```

Result:

```
bong slong mong
```

See [demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyC1KEdBtyBVQb1YX8PeJtMuSRMoXgNmFucg2Lkgpr6KdnVmbX5eun66uoKNjY2CUhJQVKE4B0TmAgml//8B)